# Which "difference" functionals only depend on the margins?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

Let the real-valued random variables $(X_1,X_2)$ have joint distribution $P_1\times P_2$. Let the distribution of $X_1-X_2$ be $P_{\mathrm{diff}}$.

Let $\psi(P_{\mathrm{diff}})$ denote a functional of distribution of the difference. The functional is *identified by the margins* if $$\psi(P_{\mathrm{diff}})=\psi_m(P_1, P_2)$$ for some functional $\psi_m$ that only depends on the marginal distributions $P_1$ and $P_2$.

**My question: What is the class of all functionals of the distribution of the difference which are identified by the margins?**

Clearly by the linearity of expectation, the expectation-of-difference functional $\psi(P_\mathrm{diff}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} x_1 - x_2 d(P_1\times P_2)(x_1,x_2)$ is identified by the margins. I cannot find other examples or prove a general theorem.

Comment: I think that $\psi:\mathcal U\to\mathbb R$ would be better, with $\mathcal U$ the set of joint distribution on $X_1$ and $X_2$ or something like that. Indeed $P_1\times P_2$ is not a set. Also is $\psi$ linear ? (some people say that functional is linear and some don't so I like specifying).

Comment: @P.Quinton Thanks for the correction about the domain. I'm interested in both the linear and nonlinear case (so no restriction, but an answer concerning linear functionals would still be interesting).

Comment: There are lots of other examples. For example, take the joint distribution, compute the marginal $P_1$, then output any functional of $P_1$ alone, such as $P_1^3[A]$ for some fixed Borel set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, or such as $E[\cos(X)]$ where $X$ has distribution $P_1$.  Or take the output to be $E[h(Y_1)]E[g(Y_2)]$ for some measurable functions $h, g$ and where $Y_i$ has distribution $P_i$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the examples. You are correct - the issue is that I incorrectly formulated the question. I've updated the question.

Comment: +1, interesting question! (Of course all functions of the expectation of the difference also work.)

Comment: The notation $P_1 \times P_2$ is somewhat misleading, since it looks like a product measure, i.e. $X_1$ and $X_2$ would be independent and the question trivial. I would prefer to call it $Q$ and write out that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are its marginal distributions. I might be missing something(?)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $P_1 \times P_2$ to be the product measure of $P_1$ and $P_2$, you can define $\bar P_2 : A \mapsto P_2(-A)$, and observe that $P_\mathrm{diff} = P_1 * \bar P_2$ where $*$ denotes the convolution of measures. Then writing $\phi : (P_1, P_2) \mapsto P_1 * \bar P_2$, you get that $\psi_m = \psi \circ \phi =: \phi_m$ satisfies the condition. This means every functional on the set of all measures that can be written as $P_\mathrm{diff}$ is *identified by the margins*.

If on the other hand you mean that $P_\mathrm{diff}$ is a measure that is the distribution of the difference of two **not necessarily independent** random variables with respective distributions $P_1$ and $P_2$, the answer is less obvious and might depend on the properties of the measured group that the $P_1, P_2$ are defined on – and you need to clarify your post.

Since the second case implies the first, I will treat the second case. The Theorem below provides a full characterization when $\psi$ is continuous and restricted to measures with a second moment condition. But first, let us give an example of a family of functionals that are identified by their margins.

**Lemma:** Write $\mathcal M_1$ for the set of all measures $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\int |x_2 - x_1|d\mu(x_1, x_2) < \infty$. For every function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, the functional
$$\psi_f : \mathcal M_1 \to \mathbb R \ , \ \mu \mapsto f\left(\int (x_2 - x_1)d\mu(x_1, x_2) \right)  \qquad (*)$$
is identified by the margins.

This Lemma has a reciprocal under slightly stronger condition. Write $\mathcal M_2$ for the set of all distributions of $(X,Y)$ with $X-Y \in L^2$, equipped with the topology of weak convergence $\mu_n \Rightarrow \mu \iff \forall f\in C_b(\mathbb R^2), \int fd\mu_n \to \int fd\mu$:

**Theorem: the set of continuous functionals on $\mathcal M_2$ that are identified by the margins is exactly the set of all $\psi_f$ with $f$ continuous.**

*The continuity of $f$ comes from considering the measures $\delta_{(x,-x)}$, with image $f(2x)$: this should be continuous in $x$. The condition that the functional be defined on $\mathcal M_2$ has two opposing effects. First, since every functional on the set of probability measures induces a functional on $\mathcal{M}_2$, every functional considered by OP falls under the scope of this theorem (provided it is continuous on $\mathcal M_2$). On the other hand, while $(*)$ must hold on $\mathcal{M}_2$, it might fail to generalize to the values taken by $\psi(\mu)$ when $\mu \notin \mathcal M_2$. In addition, $\mathcal M_2$ can likely be replaced by a larger set of probability measures without changing the validity of the theorem.*

**Note: I am not assuming that $\psi$ is linear.**

### Let’s play a game.

The game has one player, with two available actions. Starting from a distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^2$, or equivalently a pair of random variables $(X,Y)$, they can change the distribution of $(X,Y)$ while keeping constant at least one of

- the marginals, i.e. the distribution of $X$ and that of $Y$,
- the distribution of $X-Y$.

In other words, either the "projection" on either axis must be conserved, or the "projection" on the anti-diagonal must be conserved. It is clear that if $\psi$ is identified by the margins, then those two operations leave $\psi(\mu)$ invariant.

The question is: what are the classes of the set of all probability measures on $\mathbb R^2$, when two measures are invariant when we can go from one to the other (not necessarily in both directions, one is enough!) by a finite number of steps in the above game? The functional $\psi$ will be constant on them.

**Question 1: is the set of all $\psi$ that are identified by the margins, exactly the set of $\psi$ that are constant on the classes above?**

### Some observations.

- if $X-Y$ has the same distribution as $Y-X$ (its distribution is symmetric), we can arrive to the distribution $\delta_0$ in three steps. Indeed, writing $Z = (X-Y)/2$, $(Z, -Z)$ has the same distribution of the difference as $(X,Y)$, then $(Z,Z)$ has the same distribution of the marginals, and finally, $(0,0)$ has the same distribution of the difference.
- The quantity $\mathbb E[X-Y]$ (if well-defined) is left unchanged by the operations above, and for every $z\in\mathbb R$ the "random" vector $(z/2, -z/2)$ is such that $z/2+z/2 = z$, so we have at least a family indexed by $\mathbb R$ of classes.

**Question 2: starting from $(X,Y) = (z, 0)$ with probability one, can we reach any distribution of $(X,Y)$ such that $\mathbb E[X-Y] = z$?**

If the answer is yes to questions 1 and 2, then the set of $\psi$ that are identified by the margins, restricted to the set of measures where $X-Y$ is integrable, can be identified as the set of functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by the formula $\psi(\mu) = f(\mathbb E[X-Y])$ where $(X,Y)$ has distribution $\mu$. This would show that the Lemma is in fact not only sufficient, but necessary, i.e. that every functional on the set of measures with $X-Y$ integrable that is identified by the margin is of the form $\psi_f$.

### Some related questions

The following processes are legal sequences in the game.

**Q1:** fix $(X_0, Y_0)$, and define by induction $(X_{n+1},Y_{n+1})$ independent such that $2X_{n+1}$ and $-2Y_{n+1}$ both have the same distribution as $X_n-Y_n$. How does the sequence $(X_n, Y_n)$ behave as $n\to\infty$?

*We can check that*
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[(X_{n+1} - Y_{n+1})^2] &= \mathbb E [X_{n+1}^2] + \mathbb E [Y_{n+1}^2] + 2 \mathbb E [X_{n+1}]^2 \\
&= \frac12 \mathbb E[(X_n-Y_n)^2] + \frac12\mathbb E[X_n-Y_n]^2 \\
&= \frac12 \mathbb V[(X_n-Y_n)^2] + \mathbb E[X_{n+1}-Y_{n+1}]^2 
\end{align}
*so that the variance is divided by half at each step (this is true, more generally, for every cumulant that is well-defined). This means that $X_n - Y_n \to \mathbb E[X_0 - Y_0]$ in probability (and even almost surely) as $n\to\infty$. Under a condition of continuity on $\psi$ this gives us a proof of question 2 and of the Theorem. The method of cumulants would even allow a very precise central limit theorem: in distribution,*
$$ 2^{n/2} \frac{X_n-Y_n - \mathbb E[X_0-Y_0]}{\sqrt{\mathbb V(X_0 - Y_0)}} \underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \mathcal N(0,1) . $$

**Q2:** Same question, but with $X_{n+1} = (X_n-Y_n) + \epsilon_n$ and $Y_{n+1}$ an independent copy of $\epsilon_n$, where $(\epsilon_n)_n$ is a "nice" sequence of centered random variables (independent, possibly i.i.d.).

*The central limit theorem applies, meaning that we can reach distributions $(X_n, Y_n)$ with arbitrarily large $\| X_n - Y_n \|_1$ from arbitrarily small $\| X_0 - Y_0 \|_1$.*